# Properties In Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

Сделал переменную для цвета.
Выдает ошибку.
.py

```
maincolor = VariableListProperty(.9,.0,.0,1)
```

.kv

```
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: 1.0, .8
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: root.maincolor
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
                    source: 'background.png'
```

Error

```
 BuilderException: Parser: File "C:\Users\sdded\Desktop\main.kv", line 54:
 ...
      52:                       canvas:
      53:                               Color:
 >>   54:                                       rgba: root.maincolor
      55:                               Rectangle:
      56:                                       size: self.size
 ...
 AttributeError: 'Game' object has no attribute 'maincolor'
   File "C:\Users\samael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 242, in create_handler
     return eval(value, idmap), bound_list
   File "C:\Users\samael\Desktop\game\kivygame\releas\main.kv", line 54, in <module>
     rgba: set(root.maincolor)
   File "kivy\weakproxy.pyx", line 32, in kivy.weakproxy.WeakProxy.__getattr__

   File "C:\Users\samael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 923, in _build_canvas
     value, _ = create_handler(
   File "C:\Users\samael\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\builder.py", line 245, in create_handler
     raise BuilderException(rule.ctx, rule.line,
```

Comment: разве VariableListProperty это цвет ? Кажись это элемент списка, который расширяет их до желаемого размера

Comment: А какая из Propertyes, отвечает за цвет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ListProperty([r, g, b, a])
```

А в Kivy 2.0 уже завезли

```
ColorProperty([r, g, b, a])
```

Answer (score 0):

я раньше вот использовал

```
<FullImage>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: (1, 1, 1)
        Rectangle:
            texture: self.texture
            size: self.width + 20, self.height + 20
            pos: self.x - 14, self.y - 10

class FullImage(Image):
    pass
```

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы "rgb" менялось нажатием кнопки.
Для этого нужно в "rgb: root.color" переменную поместить.